# For what reasons should one use Bootstrap Testing when the sample size is large?

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap, sample

Bootstrap testing is great if we have a small sample size where the Central Limit Theorem does not apply. However, what are convincing reasons we should use Bootstrap if we do have a large sample size.

Comment: The central limit theorem still may not apply with a large sample.

Comment: The central limit theorem only applies to the **sample mean**, and no other statistics.

Comment: if the underlying distribution is unknown, then, no matter how many samples you have, bootstrapping can still add value because it doesn't assume anything about the underlying distribution.